# Can werkzeug SimpleCache share data among gunicorn threads

Tags: flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

I have a `flask` app based on `gunicorn`. Can I use `werkzeug` `SimpleCache` to share data among `gunicorn` threads?

Comment: from werkzeug SimpleCache docs: 
> Simple memory cache for single process environments. This class exists mainly for the development server and is not 100% thread safe.